# Find folders name with a pattern

Tags: c#, regex, directory

I've got a path in which there are more folders. Some of the folders can have a pattern which looks like this: "1.0.0" or "1.0.0.0" (can be any number but with this format of dots between them).

I'm trying to use a regular expression which works fine with Regex.Match but it's not working on `Directory.GetDirectories(path, regexPattern)`
The expression itself I want to use is: `@"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.\d+)*"`

How can I use that expression with `GetDirectories` method? Or any other way to find the folders I'm searching?

Comment: `Directory.GetDirectories()` argument is not a regex pattern. It's a glob, like "*.xaml".

Comment: Ok so what is a correct glob pattern in this case?

Comment: You can't do that with a glob. See my answer to continue using you regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directory does not uses regex to match the names of the directories, it uses a searchPatern that is the common way we use it under command prompt (`*.*, *.jpg` etc).

You have to get all directories and then apply your regex to filter out some directories

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.\d+)*");

var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                     .Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path))
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

`Directory.GetDirectories()` argument is not a regex pattern. It's a glob, like "*.xaml".

You can do that instead:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(path).Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x))
```

Comment: That's a gift from C# 3 called LINQ. Once you know it, you can't live without :-)

Comment: Digging out an old answer, I don't think this answer is complete or became outdated. When trying to use `regex.IsMatch` I get 'cannot choose method from method group'.

Comment: Indeed @Krystian, I updated the answer to disambiguate the call.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use regex in the method. The second parameter is of type SearchOptions. If you want AllDirectories or TopDirectoryOnly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx

You can instead just use a search term like this:

```
                    Dim myDir As New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)
                    Dim myFiles As IO.FileInfo() = myDir.GetFiles("1.0.0*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Benoit said, `GetDirectories()` uses simple command line wildcards, not regexes. To do what you want, you need to enumerate the folder names and test them with a regex:

```
foreach (var d in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
    if (Regex.IsMatch(d, @"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.\d+)*"))
        // d is a match
```